# <td> has twice as much width as it should when having an <img> with witdth=50% inside

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><img width="50%" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" /></td>
        <td>Text here</td>
        <td>Some more text here</td>
        <td>Some more text over here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jd6ukp3p/

I only tested this in Chrome on Mac. It seems like a really stupid thing but I can't seem to find a solution for that.

The problem is that I want the td tag to be the same width as the image.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding your problem correctly, it works fine for me on Chrome in Windows.

Comment: Is this more what you want https://jsfiddle.net/tL845qj7/? Or this https://jsfiddle.net/h6y1hdnj/1/?

Comment: So it might be a rendering issue. I'll check that out on Chrome in Windows as well.

Comment: I think he wants the TD only to be as "width" as the image, not more than that.

Comment: Right, exactly, sorry not to be clear enough.

Comment: cabellicard: This is doesn't solve my problem because I have more tds, I've just shown this as an example.

Comment: I think this is correct behavior. The `td` doesn't have a `width` specified so it gets its `width` from its contents which happens to be the `300px` wide `img`. The `img` is then told to have a `width` which is `50%` of it's parent (the `td`). It's a chicken and egg situation: how wide should the `td` be if the `img` is to be `50%` of the `td`'s `width` which is dependent on the `width` of the `img`?

Comment: You are absolutely right! I didn't think of it like this. My thought was that <img width="50%"> actually takes the width of the image (which in this case is 300px) and cuts it half. Then the td looks at it and adjusts its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="50%"><img width="100%" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" /></td>
    <td>Text here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you wrote it, you're setting the image to be 50% the size of the td (that has no size).

**Edit based on comments:**

For a td that is half the width of the image (in this case 300px), in a static solution:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="150"><img width="100%" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" /></td>
    <td>Text here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comments, I have more than 2 tds, this will set the td to be 50% of the table as far as I understand which is not desirable.

Comment: what is desired then? delete "width=50%" and it will be flowing width.

Comment: Desired is to have 50% width of the image, not the full width.

Comment: Well that's not very general solution when the images are not the same width but in my case this wins :) - which means this worked, so if you change the solution to that, I'm gonna mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a "general solution" to this, you'd need javascript to get the width of the image, and then set the td to half of that dynamically. This is way off the scope of the question you asked though.

Comment: It is indeed, for my purpose this works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table border="1" width="100%">
     <tr>
        <td width="50%"><img width="100%" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" /></td>
        <td>Text here</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sqhbh7jo/)